# jQuery autocomplete shows old results when none

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocomplete and I am having issues.
When there are no results in the source instead of getting no proposals in the autocomplete I get the previous proposed results.

This is my code:

```
$("#searchEmployeeSkillSelectorDashboard").autocomplete(
    {

    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Skills/SkillsSearch',
            data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {

                if (data.length > 0) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {

                    return item;

                    }));
                }
                /*else {

                 noResult = { label: "No results found" };
                 response($.map(noResult, function(item) {

                     return item;

                    }));

                }*/

            },
           error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (e, i) {

        if (i.item.val == null)
            return;

        var selected_skills = [];

        $("#skillSearchSelectedItems").find("div").each(function () { selected_skills.push(this.id); });

        for (var s = 0; s < selected_skills.length; s++) {
            if (selected_skills[s] == i.item.val) {

                var modal = $('#reportsModal');
                modal.text("The skill: " + i.item.label + " is already in the skill search list!");

                return;
            }
            else {
                var modal = $('#reportsModal');
                modal.text("");
            }
        }

        var newSkillDiv = $('<div class="span8" style="border:0.5px solid;margin:5px;padding:5px;border-radius:5px;" name="' + i.item.label + '" id="' + i.item.val + '"><p class="text-info">' + i.item.label + '</p> <span style="color:#a8a8a8;">    Skill Level:   </span><select class="span1 grades"><option value="0" selected="selected">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select>   <span style="color:#a8a8a8;">Months worked on :</span><select class="span2 months"><option value="1">1 to 3 Months</option><option value="2">3 to 6 Months</option><option value="3">6 to 12 Months</option><option value="4">1 to 3 Years</option><option value="5">3 to 6 Years</option><option value="6">More than 6 Years</option></select>   <span style="color:#a8a8a8;">Last used :</span><input type="text" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" class="datepicker span2 lastused"  placeholder="Last date used" >               <i onclick="removeSkillDiv(\'' + i.item.val + '\')" style="float:right" class="icon-remove"></i></div>');

        $('#skillSearchSelectedItems').prepend(newSkillDiv);
    },
    close: function (e, i) {
        this.value = '';
        $('#searchEmployeeSkillSelectorDashboard').val('');
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy" });
    },
    minLength: 0
}).click(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val());
    }
    );
```

This part is making an issue

```
success: function(data) {

                if (data.length > 0) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {

                    return item;

                    }));
                }
                /*else {

                 noResult = { label: "No results found" };
                 response($.map(noResult, function(item) {

                     return item;

                    }));

                }*/

            }
```

Since I am not able to force the autocomplete to empty the proposals:

[Should not be getting data picture - here I should be getting no results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9uoJ.png)

The Json and also the Class controllers are checked and are returning no results - empty arrays... These are not the source of the problem.

Also when I remove the commented part in the else it works fine - displays "No results found" - this is where I would like to force the empty array(do not want anything displayed) .

I tried returning an empty array in the else block but it runs the ajax autocomplete without ending-displays the smooth screen and loads forever without stop.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
success: function(data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            response($.map(data, function(item) {
                return item;
            }));
        } else {
            this.value = ''
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get the same results as before - repeating of the previous proposals.

Comment: @VladimirKocisTubic Is it possible for you to create a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: Since I am using ajax as as source this is not that simple for me to do.

Comment: I am wondered why the simple return: in the else block also does not work here...

Answer (score 0):

Return Empty object in response in case of no data as shown below. Hope this work for you.

```
success: function(data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            response($.map(data, function(item) {
                return item;
            }));
        } else {
            response([]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check this out. i have created a fiddle and it works here if no data is returned.Strange it didn't work for you.   http://jsfiddle.net/Makarand_Patil/32Bck/1622/

Comment: What you made behaves also strange, try typing "hllll" , you will get the results that haven't got all the letters included.

Comment: check the link buddy. i have used google search link for getting the result. so the search result is same as google search autocomplete. my intention was just to get some data on entering some text using ajax and show empty when no data  is returned from the service. Search hllll in google and you will get the same autocomplete result as mine.